# How to connect to github via netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, github

So I'm trying to connect to github via netbeans and uploading a project.

The steps I have taken:

1. right click project - initialize git repository
2. right-click project - commit
3. right-click project - remote - push...

When I am in the push menu:

```
specify git repository location:
git@github.ugent.be:brosseel/oefen2.git

private/public key:
Users/Username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

NEXT>>
```

I get:

```
Error : Cannot connect to the remote repository at git@github.ugent.be:brosseel/oefen2.git
```

How to troubleshoot that error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work if your repo exist first on GitHub (and https://github.ugent.be/brosseel/oefen2.git doesn't seem to exist).

You need to initialize an empty repo of that name, and then try to push form NetBeans.

You also can use the https url:

```
https://github.ugent.be/brosseel/oefen2.git
```

And put your GitHub username and password.

But again, that supposes you have created a repo of that name on GitHub prior to trying to push to said repo.